# How to run known method of object variable?

Tags: c#, object, methods

I have `public object LastControl` which will contain custom classes, some of which have Resize() method. I want to know how to find out if current value is of a class that has this method and in that case run it.

As of now, I get errors when trying to compile `LastControl.Resize()` because the type object itself doesn't have that method. Casting as control class could be an easy solution, but there are multiple classes, so I don't know what to do here. I figured I should start with using `GetType` in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reflection-based way, as you alluded to by `GetType`, uses the [`GetMethod` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx). You can use it to get a [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) instance on which you can then call the [`Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) to execute the method.

A cleaner way, however, would be to declare an interface that provides a `Resize()` method:

```
public interface IResizeable
{
    void Resize();
}
```

In any custom class of yours that has a `Resize()` method, you could implement that interface. Then, for checking whether the current value of `LastControl` has a `Resize()` method, you try to cast the object by using `as`, and if the result is not `null`, you can safely call the `Resize()` method:

```
IResizeable resizeable = LastObject as IResizeable;
if (resizeable != null) {
    resizeable.Resize();
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing it. The line `IResizeable resizeable = LastObject as IResizeable;` results in `resizeable` always being null. I'm new to interfaces, so I'm not sure if I did everything right.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. The class should have `ClassName : IResizeable` in it. In my case it's `InfoWindow : Game1.IResizeable`. Thanks, this works great!

Comment: @user1306322: Yes, sorry, `ClassName : IResizeable` - that's what I meant by *implement that interface*. Glad it works for you :-)

Comment: @Fuex: What method should that delegate point to? Without the interface (or reflection), it's not known whether the object has a `Resize()` method.